# Python package in private repo with CLI utility - how to deploy, use, and structure

Tags: python-3.x, git, package

I've established a private github organization for common python repos - each repo is basically a unique python 3rd party package (like numpy for example) but that are homegrown.  These are to be used across different projects.

At the moment, the repos are just source packages, not compiled with wheels or sdist for releases - so each has a setup.py, and directory structure for the modules/business logic of the library.  Basically the repos look somewhat like this: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/

At the moment, I don't want to address compiling releases or a private PyPI server.  **What I need help/guidance on is what if its not just a library, but also has a CLI tool (that uses the library).**

I expect the user to one of several things: clone it, set PYTHONPATH/PATH accordingly, and use it, or package and pip install it.  but should the CLI tool be included inside that repo, or outside?  how does one call it (ie. python -m ).

Whats strange to me is that packages seem more geared towards true libraries and not libraries+tools.  Any help in my thought process on this and how to invoke?

Comment: https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#scripts

Comment: Thanks phd.  I've come across this before and figured that would somehow come to play - I struggle with understanding how that benefits though.  So i define an entry point.  But I need to still be able to call it like any other executable and would still need to manage the environment.  does it just mean that I can invoke the python where the package is installed and call it (and it python just finds it)?  (ie. python blah_package, and blah_package is my CLI tool defined as an entry point)?

Comment: Entry points are scripts installed in `bin` directories.

Comment: Ok, so I found this site: https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html which describes the entry_points as well as setup-->scripts directive.  My question now is: I use virtual environments.  Normal usage is to source the bin/activate.  Now if I pip install a package with an entry_point defined, presumably this updates path.  But whats not clear to me is how that works for my current shell environment.  ie, I activate, pip install, then later on, new terminal window I activate a new venv session.  how is my shell now able to resolve the scripts entrypoint

Comment: Virtual environments are separate, every one has its own `bin/` directory. Activating a virtual environment means prepending the `bin/` directory to `$PATH` so scripts installing in `bin/` are readily available but not scripts in a different venv.

Comment: oh...I see where your going with this.  The setuptools installer somehow manages creation of a wrapper that gets placed in the "venv" bin folder.  I can play around, the spec isn't fully clear on that: https://packaging.python.org/specifications/entry-points/ . 
 I'm not a huge fan of empirical learning, but that would make sense for then having that available on path for the shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @phd for helping me walk the dog.

For my package project, I define a setup.py (surrogate makefile in python's parlance) which defines this entry point:

```
setuptools.setup(
    name="pkg_name",                  # Replace with your package name
    version="0.0.1",                  # see pep 440
    ...
    scripts=['bin/simple_cli.py'],    # callable script to register (updates PATH)
    ...
)
```

Now in the package project itself, basic structure is as follows and I'll highlight the **bin/** directory:

```
$ tree -L 3
.
├── bin
│   └── simple_cli.py
├── contributing.md
├── LICENSE
├── makefile
├── pkg_name
│   ├── example_module.py
│   ├── __init__.py
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
└── tests
    ├── test_main.py
```

Once this is built (sdist, wheels, etc), we can use pip install .  I test this in a virtual environment and here is where simple_cli.py exists:

[image]

The comments above have some references, but end-state is the file is installed in the venv bin/ directory (which is available on PATH with an activated venv).